# What does the splash command do in grub?

Tags: boot, grub2, kernel, plymouth

When looking in the /boot/grub/grub.cfg file, one can find the line where grub passes control to the linux kernel:

```
linux   /boot/vmlinuz-5.3.0-40-generic 
root=UUID=7275fcb8-061b-4fcc-b5d8-c311381eaada ro  quiet splash $vt_handoff
```

At the end of the line, ro, quiet and splash are called.

From the kernel command line, ro and quiet are explained:
https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man7/kernel-command-line.7.html

Yet there is no mention of splash. The only place where I could find an explanation was in a [reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxquestions/comments/8hocyq/kernel_boot_options_splash_vs_nosplash_vs_just/), stating it was an option to be passed to plymouth, a graphical boot loader

My question is: **How could I have known that splash, was referring to the plymouth boot loader?**

In other words, how come splash isn't listed in the documentation for linux kernel commands?